# Form not submitting after load() in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have two pages, `main.php` and `user_profile.php`.

I load `user_profile.php` inside `#user_profile_content` which exist in `main.php`

Here is some code in `user_profile.php`

```
<table><tbody>
    <tr>
    <th><?php echo $lang['SEND_MESSAGE']; ?></th>
    <td>
      <a href="#send_msg" class="modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons">mail</i></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table></tbody>
```

This will open a modal which contains a form

```
<div id="send_msg" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span><?php echo $lang['SEND_MSG_TO']." : ".$user_username; ?></span>
      <form id="send_msg_form" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="Message" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['WRITE_MESSAGE']?>" />

    </div>
    <div class="send_modal_footer">
      <button id="submit_msg" class="btn-flat" type="submit">Send</button
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  $('#send_msg').modal();
```

Also php :

```
  //send msg to user
  if (isset($_POST['Message']))
    {
      $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['Message']);
      $query_username_result = mysqli_query($connection,
      "INSERT INTO msg
       SET
       TXT='{$message}',
       FROM_USERNAME='{$username_session}',
       TO_USERNAME='{$user_name}',
       FROM_ID='{$my_id}',
       TO_ID='{$user_id}',
       FROM_ID_STATUS=1,
       ON_DATE='{$now}'");
    }
 ?>
```

Above codes all in `user_profile.php` which will be loaded in `main_pm.php` by this code :

```
var USER_ID = 0;
function UserProfile(user_id)
{
USER_ID = user_id; // now its global variable
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "main.php",
                  data: {ID: USER_ID},
                  success: function(msg)
                  {
                    $('#user_profile_content').load('user_profile.php?ID='+USER_ID);
                 },
                  error: function()
                  {
                      alert("error");
                  }
              });
}
```

`user_profile.php?ID=+USER_ID` Will be loaded here :

```
 <div class="option_dialog" id="user_profile">
 <div class="close_option">User profile <img onclick="user_profile()" 
 style="float:right;height:20px" src="img/close.png"></div>
 <div id="user_profile_content" style="overflow:scroll;max-height:400px">

 <!--user profile will be loaded here based on returned value -->   

 </div>
 </div>
```

Everything works fine, but the most confusing issue, the form is not working after all this, but if I try it directly from `user_profile.php` it works fine

Comment: This looks like it could need a script tag: `$('#send_msg').modal();` Where do you send the form?  Why is the submit button a submit and not a button if you use ajax?

Comment: `<form id="send_msg" method="post">` Specify the form action where you want it to go here, maybe?

Comment: I've already this script there,what do you mean exactly,be clear

Comment: @Adder i also tried action , but without not success,it's not submitting,and console not log the form submission to see where is the problem or is it even post it or not

Comment: Put the `form` tag before the `<div class="modal-content">` ? So that elements are properly nested?

Comment: @Adder didn't work,there is also another simple form without modal,that one not work too,i don't know why

Comment: You also have duplicate ids: `id="send_msg"` . Try changing this and both changes I suggested at the same time.

Comment: @Adder right now ids diffrenet in my project,but not working:( i can't make it wooooooooorkkkkkkk

Comment: You need to identify what is not working. Is it the eventlistener? Is it the PHP script? How far does it get.

Comment: Make a minimal viable usecase that will trigger the error, that will make it easier for us to help you